# Confused about the animation classes~

Tags: iphone, animation, methods

Today I started to learn iPhone simple animations, but I was totally Confused about so many animations ,now I have know some like CAAnimation, CATransaction and so on~  how can I distinguish them or if there are some documents about them  to help me know how to use these class and the different effects among them;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend to read at first [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). It describes all basic [classes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006085-SW6), provided examples and link to sample sources.

Comment: cool I have printed it ths a lot~